# Optimistic locking when saving record

Tags: slingr

In an app on slingr.io there is a listener that gets executed when a webhook arrives. Inside that listener we have a code like this:

```
// process webhook
// ...
record.field('status').val('active');
sys.data.save(record);
```

In the logs we are seeing that in many cases we are getting the following error:

```
» 2019-09-25 18:52:00.349 ERROR system@nbt.slingrs.io Optimistic locking exception saving record [Order T792-18]
```

This is not happening all the time, but only in some cases. What's the reason and how to prevent it from happening?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to concurrency issue as many webhooks are probably arriving at almost the same time and so multiple threads are trying to update the record concurrently.

The most convenient way to avoid this problem when editing a record is to use the `lock()` method like this:

```
// process webhook
// ...
record.lock(function(record) {
  record.field('status').val('active');
  sys.data.save(record);
);
```

That will put a semaphore if other threads try to update the record at the same time.